# When should I use 'thaw' and 'melt'?

Tags: vocabulary

*Thaw* seems to be used when thawing something, like food. *Melt* seems to be used with ice. Some dictionary definitions seem to conflict with these statements. When should each word be used?

Comment: Candles melt, but they don't thaw.

Comment: @Strawberry,you mean the burning flame at the wick of the candle melts?

Comment: No. The wick burns. The wax melts.

Comment: @Strawberry Well, to be more accurate, a lit candle's wax will both burn *and* melt ([additional reading](https://uwaterloo.ca/chem13-news-magazine/february-2019/feature/study-rate-candle-burning)).

Comment: @Arctiic Yes, but don't put tomatoes in a fruit salad.

Comment: @我的不好 Also note, although this doesn't answer your post specifically since you're asking for when each would be most suitably be qualified for use, rather than specific instances where they may be disqualified for mutually interchangeable use, Strawberry's comment brings up a good point: hierarchically speaking, the term "thaw" to my knowledge exclusively refers to processes that qualify as "defrosting", whereas "melt" is not exclusive to that sense.

Comment: In other words, thawing is only used when referring to subjects at or below it's chemical freezing point, whereas melting can apply regardless of it's thermal attributes.  Usage example: you can thaw a windshield, whereas you can both melt the ice off a windshield as well as melt the windshield glass itself.

Comment: @Arctiic On a point of pedantry (this is an English language site, after all), in all instances above, it's 'its'.

Comment: Not really sure it qualifies as an answer, but I always understood Thawing to imply that the ice is only part of the whole. whereas melting implies the whole thing liquifies. eg: Chicken thaws, because the chicken as a whole remains a cohesive object, only the ice-crystals in it have melted. whereas a candle melts because the whole thing is made of wax and all of it has liquified.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As I understand it, "melt" implies a phase change from a solid (often a frozen) state to a liquid or near-liquid state.

- An ice cube melts when it warms and turns from a solid into a liquid.
- Cheese melts, turning from a firm solid, into a liquid or goo.
- Iron melts in a forge, turning into a (very hot) liquid.

"Thaw" is generally used to describe cases where a frozen item warms enough for *ice* to melt, but without a complete phase change. E.g.

- Frozen meat should thaw before cooking. The ice particles in it melt, but it does not liquify.
- [Permafrost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permafrost) (frozen soil, usually found in the arctic) *thaws*, it does not melt. Individual ice crystals in the soil melt as the soil warms (becoming liquid), but the soil itself does not turn into a liquid.

Comment: So I understand that thawing allows it to still remain solid...

Comment: For some or all of the object in question, yes. In the soup example above, the water in the soup melts, but the carrots do not melt. The soup, therefore, thaws. Similarly, in my permafrost example, the ice in the soil melts, but the rest of the soil does not become a liquid. Therefore, the ice crystals melt, but the soil thaws.

Comment: 'solid' yes. 'frozen' no - or not necessarily.

Comment: Thaw means unfreeze and refers to *water*/ice (in food, soil, etc), melt means liquefy (any chemical compound). Not everything that thaws stays solid.

Comment: I'd say (maybe pedantically) thawing is more to do with getting back to a natural state, or the melting of ice from an object, than anything to do with phase change.  If a lake has a layer of ice on it, when the ice melts, the lake thaws.  And I reckon there are instances where they can be used interchangeably - frost or snow can either melt or thaw.

Answer (score 25):

- Something frozen will THAW to a solid state.
- Something frozen will MELT to a liquid state.

So ice would melt (being frozen water), a frozen sausage would thaw (to a sausage).

To be confusing, frozen cheese thaws, and then as it gets hotter, melts into a liquid.

This is an excellent question - as a native english speaker, I had to think about it for a moment.

Comment: So only ice can melt.

Comment: Possible exception - Frozen soup would thaw, and not melt, perhaps because its quite viscous.

Comment: @我的不好 no - I would say any solid that can liquefy would be melting.   Thawing leaves it as a a solid still.   Chris' answer about phase change is excellent.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker so I'm a bit hesistant to start an argument, but I feel like this answer is (at least partly) wrong. When winter ends, the snow and ice will disappear. It thaws. (cfr: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/thaw). Also: from a physical (and less linguistical) standpoint you could also say that when food thaws, the relevant solid particles inside are undergoing a state change from solid to liquid.

Comment: @Opifex I think that while the snow & ice will melt, it is the winter itself which will thaw. (Or maybe, the world which is thawing)

Comment: UuDdLrLrSs,(the world which is thawing),you are referring to global warming

Comment: @Criggie I get what you mean

Comment: As a native speaker, I agree with the objection raised by @Opifex .  The situation is not as simple as this answer proposes.  In actual common usage there seem to be complex unstated rules: it would be perfectly natural to describe ice that had trapped a ship as "thawing," but it would be quite strange to say that the ice in your glass of water had "thawed."  "Thaw" seems to carry with it a connotation of no longer being stuff/stiff perhaps?

Comment: @GrandOpener in that example you're talking not just about ice melting, but ice melting as a result of warmer weather. I think thaw carries connotations of a change in the environment.

Comment: @barbecue That's an excellent point too.  I don't myself have a firm grasp of exactly the limits of those unspoken rules are--just that thaw to solid and melt to liquid isn't fully accurate.

Comment: @barbecue another way to look at it, perhaps, could be that *melting* specifically means becoming liquid, while *thawing* implies returning to the *natural* state/reversing the effects of freezing?

Comment: @crizzis I think you're onto something with that. Melting definitely means going from solid to liquid, but thawing means going from frozen to not-frozen, regardless of whether it's liquid or not. If I thaw a steak, it goes from a hard solid to a soft squishy solid, but still solid. If I thaw some soup, it goes from solid to liquid.

Comment: @GrandOpener I think melt vs. thaw might have something to do with the completeness of the melt. Ice that traps a ship just has to melt enough to break up under force - there will still be unmelted ice around when the ship frees itself. The ice is thawing from a completely solid state to a less solid state, but is not melting completely. To me, melting implies a more or less complete change to liquid, while thaw suggests there's still some solidity.

Comment: I think a key part of "thaw" is an implication that it is coming to roughly room temperature.  Every case I can think of where it is natural involves something being frozen that is brought to roughly room temperature.  Melting can involve any temperature change.  (You can melt an iron bar, for instance.)

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps colloquially, "thaw" can refer to melting caused by nature.

As in, "It was April, and the lake had thawed out."

(Sometime the warming of spring is called the "Spring thaw")

Answer (score 5):

The top current answers seem to focus on phase change; I think this is too narrow a view. Instead, as [@Zenzizenzizenzic's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/257128/37343) mentions: *lake thaw*!

I would therefore explain the difference in a slightly more general way:

- *Melting*: the nature of the object *changes*. A *ice* cube becomes *water*, for example.
- *Thawing*: the nature of the object *does not change*. A frozen lake, after thawing, is still a lake.

If you refer to something in the same way before and after: it *thawed*. Otherwise, it *melted*.

Comment: M,so they are interchangeable???

Comment: @我的不好: Not at all, _melt_ implies a change of name while _thaws_ implies that the name remains unchanged -- they are thus non-overlapping, and in general complementary.

Comment: +1 A lake’s ice melts, but the lake thaws.   I wonder if cheese fits here, too?   You melt cheese... that gets back to the phase conversation.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, note that there are industry/regulatory implications when using specific verbiage such as "thawing" (as applied to industrial/commercial food processing sectors under federal inspection programs).  In the USA, for example, these can fall under either USDA FSIS' or FDA's policy arenas depending on the product(s) in question.  For example, under the [FDA Food Code 2017](https://www.fda.gov/media/110822/download), "thawing" is defined as and must meet the requirements of:

> > 3-501.13 Thawing.
> > Except as specified in (D) of this section, TIME/TEMPERATURE CONTROL FOR SAFETY FOOD shall be thawed:
> > (A) Under refrigeration that maintains the FOOD temperature at 5°C (41°F) or less; or
> > (B) Completely submerged under running water:
> > (1) At a water temperature of 21°C (70°F) or below,
> > (2) With sufficient water velocity to agitate and float off loose particles in an overflow, and
> > (3) For a period of time that does not allow thawed portions of READY-TO-EAT FOOD to rise above 5°C (41°F), or
> > (4) For a period of time that does not allow thawed portions of a raw animal FOOD requiring cooking as specified under ¶ 3-401.11(A) or (B) to be above 5°C (41°F), for more than 4 hours including:
> > (a) The time the FOOD is exposed to the running water and the time needed for preparation for cooking, or (b) The time it takes under refrigeration to lower the FOOD temperature to 5°C (41°F);
> > (C) As part of a cooking process if the FOOD that is frozen is:
> > (1) Cooked as specified under ¶¶3-401.11(A) or (B) or § 3-401.12, or
> > (2) Thawed in a microwave oven and immediately transferred to conventional cooking EQUIPMENT, with no interruption in the process; or
> > (D) Using any procedure if a portion of frozen READY-TO-EAT FOOD is thawed and prepared for immediate service in response to an individual CONSUMER'S order.
> > (E) REDUCED OXYGEN PACKAGED FISH that bears a label indicating that it is to be kept frozen until time of use shall be removed from the reduced oxygen environment:
> > (1) Prior to its thawing under refrigeration as specified in ¶(A) of this section; or
> > (2) Prior to, or Immediately upon completion of, its thawing using procedures specified in ¶ (B) of this section.

A similar vernacular term would be "slacking", which is instead defined as:

> > "Slacking" means the process of moderating the temperature of a FOOD such as allowing a FOOD to gradually increase from a temperature of -23°C (-10°F) to -4°C (25°F) in preparation for deep-fat frying or to facilitate even heat penetration during the cooking of previously block-frozen FOOD such as shrimp.

And finally, the term "melting" is typically not applied upon finished or work-in-progress product (for that, we would use verbiage such as "temperature-abused" or "out-of-spec"), and is instead typically seen when describing product-external components that present a concern for cross-contamination hazards when temperature control is not properly enforced, e.g., fresh produce packed on ice formed with non-potable water source(s).

Comment: https://www.fda.gov/media/110822/download
I do not think  this should be included...

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want a generally understood definition, without scientific specificity, or literary license (such as the thawing of relations between countries after war, or the melting of one's resolve).

Frozen liquids such as snow and ice melt. But so do normally-solid materials such as plastic and cheese and even rocks, at high enough temperatures. Anything that melts goes from solid to liquid or semi-liquid state. Becoming liquid is central to the definition.

"Thaw" means coming out of ice or a frozen state. So a frozen solid (like a steak) thaws and remains solid. A forest (trees, terrain) can thaw after winter, as the snow on it melts.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference has been described by Chris Keefe already but here is some supplementary material.

There are figurative uses of both terms, thaw and melt, which are not interchangeable. In politics and elsewhere you might say that you were hoping for a thaw in relations between the US and China or between two people or factions. Melt would be wrong here. You might speak though of melting someone's heart in the sense of causing them an extreme positive emotional change of state.

There are two related terms which can be distinguished.

If a bank account is frozen by the bank because of suspected fraud then you would ask them to unfreeze it. This also applies metaphorically to mechanisms which have become stuck in some way like a hinge rusting solid. If you put oil on it and it now works you could say you managed to unfreeze it.

If you take an item from the freezer and put it in the microwave oven you would say you are going to defrost it and the microwave may even have a defrost setting. This is different from scarping the frost off the car windscreen in winter. I am not sure this is universal in all dialects but it is common in the one I speak - south east England. I am not sure why we do not say we are going to thaw it which would be logical although we may or may not be going to melt it as well as defrost it.

Answer (score 1):

Thawing means to take something that was previously frozen and warm it until it is no longer frozen.

Melting can happen at any temperature and implies a loss of shape. When butter melts, it stops being a block shape and becomes a puddle of liquid butter. You can also melt iron at very high temperatures. Neither of these could be described as "thawing"

Since a frozen chicken keeps its shape when warmed to room temperature, that would be described as "thawing". But an ice cube, when warmed, becomes a puddle of water, so it should be described as "melting". However, an object encased in ice would be thawed by melting the ice.

Comment: Can you distinguish between 'thaw' and 'defrost' in relation to food? The earth can thaw but not defrost whereas actively heating up a chicken until no longer frozen can be defrosting, but can it also be thawing?

Comment: 'thaw' and 'defrost' are synonyms for food. Frost is the thin layer of ice covering things, so any man-made process that melts that ice is 'defrosting'

Answer (score 0):

*Thaw* and *defrost* mean the same thing: "return from frozen to its expected state."

*Melt* means "change state from a solid into a liquid (due to heat)"

Here, "expected state" means exactly what you think it means—typically the state it's in at room temp or fridge temp. That's all there is to it. The other answers make it seem more complicated than it is.

Answer (score -1):

The distinction is also about the direction of the action.

We have a *thaw* in the spring as the weather warms up, so it's a slower action with the temperature change generally applied by the *environment*.

We can *melt* a piece of ice, or soup, directly on a cooker. It's faster and *directed at the item*.

You melt a thing (that can melt), while the thaw comes to that thing.

Many solid objects (esp. frozen food) do not conduct heat very well, so the direct application of heat on a cooker just isn't satisfactory - the outside can be burnt, while the centre is still frozen (see the 'Baked Alaska' cake/pudding/treat), so such *frozen foods need to be thawed*.

It should be noted that the microwaves in a microwave oven are not readily absorbed by ice, so are not really suitable for 'thawing' food. Also microwaves don't reach very far into the thawed food, so may need 'standing time' to allow the heat to reach all parts. Microwave cooking has helped the misuse of many phrases used in cooking (as had the availability of freezers).

Comment: So, when I thaw frozen meat by using the "defrost" setting on my microwave, I should describe that as melting it? I don't think this is a good way to distinguish the two. Just because a microwave doesn't do a good job of thawing out frozen food, doesn't mean that's not what it is attempting to do. What about the people describing the icecaps as "melting" due to global warming? Should they use "thaw"?

Comment: @ColleenV If you microwave Ice, it will 'slowly' melt, taking longer than expected compared to heating water. You are right that If you try to microwave frozen meat it will start thawing, and the outside will cook, but you can still be left with a block of frozen meat in the middle (or barely defrosted, uncooked!), which is the hazard.